# scikit MLPClassifier couldn't fit xor problem

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network, xor

My teacher asked us to use the scikit mlpclassifier to solve the xor problem, and asked to use 2 hidden layers the first with 4 units and the second with 2 units, and the identity for activation and lbfgs as solver

```
x = [ [ 0 , 0 ] , [ 0 , 1 ] , [ 1 , 0 ] , [ 1 , 1 ] ]
y = [ 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 ]
clf = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes = (4,2), activation = 'identity', solver = 'lbfgs')
clf.fit(x,y)
clf.predict(x)
# output:array([1, 0, 0, 0])
```

I don't why it fails to predict correctly, I thought any combination of linear functions could solve a non linear problem

Comment: I'm guessing your teacher's next lesson will be describing why this won't work.

Comment: Agree with @rickhg12hs.  In advance of that, consider changing some of those parameters and see what you can get!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because code works as expected